# how to encode POST data using python's urllib

Tags: python, django, urllib, http-error

I'm trying to connect to my Django server using a client side python script.  Right now I'm just trying to connect to a view and retrieve the HttpResponse.  The following works fine

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "http://localhost:8000/minion/serve"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
print html
```

However if I change it to

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "http://localhost:8000/minion/serve"
values = {'name': 'Bob'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
print html
```

I get `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`.  Am I doing something wrong here?  Here are the tutorials I was trying to follow, http://techmalt.com/?p=212 http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html.

EDIT: tried to make the following change as per That1Guy's suggestion (other lines left the same)

```
request =  urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, data)
```

This returned the same error message as before.

EDIT:  It seems to work if I change the page I'm viewing so the error isn't in the client side script.  So in light of that revelation, here's the server side view that's being accessed:

```
def serve(request):
    return HttpResponse("You've been served!")
```

As you can see, it's very straight forward.

EDIT: Tested to see if Internal Error might be caused by missing csrf token, but csrf_exempt decorator failed to resolve error.

Comment: In your browser, try `http://localhost:8000/minion/serve?name=bob` and see what happens

Comment: Pass `data` to `urlopen`.

Comment: @karthikr that works fine, gives the output expected

Comment: @That1Guy that returns the same error message as before

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out with this. [How to POST dictionary from python script to django url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420594/how-to-post-dictionary-from-python-script-to-django-url)

Turns out my url was missing a trailing slash.  It's the little things that always get you I guess.